# Eclipse IDE V36 Java Null Pointer Exception - Run Configurations

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

I recently upgraded my Mac Force.com Eclipse IDE to V36 because I liked the Windows version V36.  *(Separate client engagements in case you were wondering)*

When I click Run Configurations in the Eclipse Toolbar, and try to select a Test Class in the `Test` tab, I get a Java NPE. Same result if I click on an existing configuration with just a Project assigned to it.

[image]

Eclipse and Force.com IDE are all up to date
[image]

Eclipse Log shows this error:

```
!ENTRY com.salesforce.ide.core 0 0 2016-05-17 10:54:58.883
!MESSAGE DEBUG [2016-05-17 10:54:58,882] (BaseContextHandler.java:getBean:181) - Got bean of class 'com.salesforce.ide.core.model.Component$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6361ae6c' for id 'ApexClass'


!ENTRY com.salesforce.ide.core 0 0 2016-05-17 10:54:58.883
!MESSAGE DEBUG [2016-05-17 10:54:58,883] (ComponentFactory.java:getComponentByComponentType:516) - Found component of type ApexClass for id 'ApexClass' and object type 'ApexClass'


!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2016-05-17 10:54:58.903
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.salesforce.ide.apex.internal.core.ApexTestsUtils.filterSourcesByType(ApexTestsUtils.java:325)
    at com.salesforce.ide.apex.internal.core.ApexTestsUtils.filterSourcesByClass(ApexTestsUtils.java:272)
    at com.salesforce.ide.apex.internal.core.ApexTestsUtils.findTestClassesInProject(ApexTestsUtils.java:84)
    at com.salesforce.ide.ui.views.runtest.TestConfigurationTab.buildTestsForProject(TestConfigurationTab.java:520)
    at com.salesforce.ide.ui.views.runtest.TestConfigurationTab.initializeFrom(TestConfigurationTab.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup.initializeFrom(AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupWrapper.initializeFrom(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupWrapper.java:194)
....
```

What it looks like is that in attempting to get a list of Apex classes so they can be filtered in the Test tab, an NPE occurs between `jFace` and `ApexTestUtils`.  No doubt I have some config issue but what might it be?  Previous install was V33 of Force.com IDE on the same Eclipse layer and that worked fine (of course, there was no `Run Configurations` in V33)

Comment: Possibly this line https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/200.eclipse/com.salesforce.ide.apex.core/src/com/salesforce/ide/apex/internal/core/ApexTestsUtils.java#L325. File (resource) `res` with no file extension causes the problem? That class seems to have been replaced in the current head...

Comment: @KeithC - Hmm, an interesting hypothesis and _why I didn't go look at idecore for that line# is a personal failing of mine :-(_ . I decided to start from scratch but with Eclipse Mars and am adding projects back one at a time until the error occurs, if at all.  Stay tuned.

Comment: Any Update on this - even I am getting the same error? :(
I m using Force - 36, Eclipse Neon, Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to make sure eclipse only loaded certain objects and not choosing the default. I deleted my workspace folder. Did a new force.com ide project and instead of letting the default option I chose the option 'Selected metadata components' and then from that list I only chose a few objects. Classes, components, pages and triggers. This extremely limited the amount of ojbects it had to parse through to generate the list of test classes and now it works. I believe there was something coming down from a managed package or something that it was unable to cycle through to look for test classes and caused the Null Pointer Exception error.